# Changing Mainactivity in Android

Tags: android, main-activity

In iOS it is very use (when using storyboard) to change root view controller.

Root view controller; Controller that loads/appears to user when user first opens the app.

Is there a way to do that in android. I have an activity (e.g. RegistrationActivity) and I want that activity to be first activity that gets loaded in  android

I can go to RegistrationActivity by following a flow, but for purposes of debugging I want to short circuit thsoe steps and want my emulator to load that activity on app launch.

Comment: Why don't you just temporarily set that activity as the launcher activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that within the `AndroidManifest.xml` the `MainActivty` declaration has the intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Simply move this to which ever activity you desire to be the root activity